# Create user on keycloak with Angular 7 by REST API

Tags: angular, keycloak, angular7

I have a little problem to register a user on Keycloak.

I use `keycloak-admin-client`:

```
let keycloakAdminClient = require('keycloak-admin-client');
```

When the client tries to create a user, the server says 403 forbidden.

```
keycloakAdminClient(clientSettings)
  .then((clients) => {
    console.log('[newRegistration - keycloakAdminClient] init success');
    console.log(clients.token);
    clients.users.create(environment.KEYCLOAK_REALM, newKeycloakUser)
      .then((createdUser) => {
        console.log('[newRegistration - keycloakAdminClient - client.users.create] success - createdUser = ' + createdUser);
        // findNewUserId(newKeycloakUser.username);
        return newKeycloakUser.username;
      })
      .catch((err) => {

        console.log('[newRegistration - keycloakAdminClient - client.users.create] error - code = ', err);
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('[newRegistration - keycloakAdminClient] init error - code = ', err);
  });
console.log('[newRegistration] END');
};
```

This is the settings of client:

```
 export const environment = {
  production: false,
  KEYCLOAK_URL: 'http://10.10.15.35:8080/auth',
  KEYCLOAK_REALM: 'baulogistik_test',
  KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID: 'angular-frontend',
  BACKEND_URL: 'http://10.10.15.35:8080/api',
  CLIENT_SECRET: '296f7a0f-a0f5-4395-a120-ece8565bbce1'
};

const clientSettings = {
    production: environment.production,
    baseUrl: environment.KEYCLOAK_URL,
    client_id: environment.KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID,
    realmName: environment.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_secret: environment.CLIENT_SECRET
}
```

I can log in with the client via the secret key and get an `accessToken`.

The client has admin role.

[image: Role Settings on keycloak]

[image: client settings]

Have anybody an advice for me?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Are you sure the client is the one creating the user and you're not creating the user using your current logged in user's token?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I try to create the user by using the client access token.

Comment: Try with some HTTP client like Postman to create it. If it works, you're doing something wrong in the Angular side. If not, it is the KC server being misconfigured.

Comment: I have the same error with postman. The kc server could be misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
You have to add the roles from the realm-management client to your admin role.

[image]

After that, a user must have the admin role.
Then the clientSettings has to be extended in the Angular app:

- Add username and password of your admin user
- Modify grant_type to password

  ```
   const clientSettings = {
   production: environment.production,
   baseUrl: environment.KEYCLOAK_URL,
   client_id: environment.KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID,
   realmName: environment.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
   grant_type: 'password',//'client_credentials',
   username: environment.username,
   password: environment.password,
   client_secret: environment.CLIENT_SECRET
  ```